# How to shrink UI elements on an external display beyond its native resolution

Tags: macos, display

I am looking for an answer to help people who are in the following situation:

- They are using an external display
- The external display has resolution A x B
- The resolution in "Displays" (in System Settings) is already set to A x B (not a resolution less than A x B)
- They would like the UI elements to be smaller (artificially display with a "higher" resolution)

My specific situation:

- I have an external display with a native resolution of 1920 x 1080
- I would like be able to select a resolution greater than 1920 x 1080 in display preferences so that UI elements are smaller on the external display (2400 x 1350 would be great)
- I cannot find any way to set it to this value...

What I have tried:

1. The "Show all resolutions" slider in display preferences. This only shows resolution less than the native resolution of the external monitor.
2. Using the [BetterDisplay](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay#readme) app. Unfortunately, this costs money. I am looking for a way to do this for free if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [BetterDisplay](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay#readme) app. It has a 14-day free trial, and after that, you can purchase the pro license for $18 (as of 2023-11-27).

1. Create a "virtual screen" with the same aspect ratio as the external monitor

   1. Click the menubar icon
   2. Expand the **Displays And Virtual Screens** section
   3. Click **Create New Virtual Screen**
   4. Open the application window and navigate to **Displays** > [the virtual screen] > **Aspect ratio**
2. Add the desired resolution

   1. Select **Use custom resolution list**
   2. Add the desired resolution (ensure that it has the correct aspect ratio; otherwise it will not be accepted)
3. Mirror the virtual screen to the external display

   1. Expand **Association settings** and select **Enforce virtual screen mirrors**
   2. Associate the virtual screen with the external display (**Displays** > [the virtual screen] > **Associated displays** > **Associate this virtual screen with real display(s)** > [the external display])
4. Done! (you may need to adjust the display arrangement under the **System Preferences > Displays**)

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I am providing the only solution I found as an answer, but I am still looking for an alternative. If someone could provide a free alternative I will accept that answer. I'm also in touch with the developer of DisplayBuddy and it seems they can implement this feature as well.